# How do I fix peer dependency errors?

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, npm-install

I have an Angular project I began using a random starter project. Someone on our team attempted to clone the repo and when they did an npm install the application would not build and was giving the following errors:

```
npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/upgrade@2.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN app@0.0.0 No repository field.
```

It says angular router requires angular 2.2.0. So I manually install angular 2.2.0 and then I get the following error:

```
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@~2.1.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN codelyzer@1.0.0-beta.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@~2.1.1 but none was installed.
```

Now codelyzer reacquires the version of angular that I just upgrading from. I can easily go to the starter project and update my files but that is not going to help me to learn how to fix this issue.

How does one go about correcting what seems to be a circular dependency problem when you fix one issue only to cause another?

Comment: not really circular dependency.. `codelyzer` seems to want older version.. and `angular/router` wanted `angular version 2.2.0` even in your original error..you need to go for a higher version of codelyzer. [latest one](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/blob/master/package.json) will need `2.3.1`

Comment: Thank you. I understood that I needed codelyzer 2 from looking at the updated starter project. What I am unclear about is the process a developer goes about when trying to resolve this. When doing npm update for example, it does not update codelyzer. So does that mean I have to literally determine what versions are available and what they are comparable with? What is the point of npm if I have to do all that? Isn't that what a package manager is for?